AllowDrop not working after drag over wrong target (Image) in .NET MAUI
I encountered a strange bug/error in .met maui when dragging an object and changing the AllowDrop property.
So, I have three images, one of which is dragged onto the other two and activates the validation logic.
Here's the dragging image:
 <Image Grid.Row="0"
        x:Name="image1"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Source="{Binding FirstImageRoute}"
        Opacity="{Binding SecondImageOpacity}">
     <Image.GestureRecognizers>
         <DragGestureRecognizer
                     CanDrag="True"
                     DropCompletedCommand="{Binding DragCompleteCommand}"
                     DragStartingCommand="{Binding DragStartingCommand}"
         DragStartingCommandParameter="{x:Reference image1}">
         </DragGestureRecognizer>
     </Image.GestureRecognizers>
 </Image>

As you can see, I use Observable properties and DragGestureRecognizer. And I have an ObservableProperty called isAllow that controls whether a drop is allowed.
Here are the XAML definitions for the two target images where the first one will be dropped:
<Image x:Name="image2"
    Grid.Row="1"
       Grid.Column="1"
       Source="{Binding SecondImageRoute}"
       Opacity="{Binding FirstImageOpacity, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <DropGestureRecognizer AllowDrop="{Binding IsAllow}"
               DragOverCommand="{Binding DragOverCommand}"
               DropCommand="{Binding DropCommand}"
               x:Name="drop1">
            <DropGestureRecognizer.DragOverCommandParameter>
                <Binding Source="{x:Reference image2}"/>
            </DropGestureRecognizer.DragOverCommandParameter>
            <DropGestureRecognizer.DropCommandParameter>
                <Binding Source="{x:Reference image2}"/>
            </DropGestureRecognizer.DropCommandParameter>
        </DropGestureRecognizer>
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>

<Image x:Name="image3"
       Grid.Row="1"
       Grid.Column="0"
       Source="{Binding FirstImageRoute}"
       Opacity="{Binding SecondImageOpacity, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <DropGestureRecognizer AllowDrop="{Binding IsAllow}"
               DragOverCommand="{Binding DragOverCommand}"
               DropCommand="{Binding DropCommand}"
               x:Name="drop2">
            <DropGestureRecognizer.DragOverCommandParameter>
                <Binding Source="{x:Reference image3}"/>
            </DropGestureRecognizer.DragOverCommandParameter>
            <DropGestureRecognizer.DropCommandParameter>
                <Binding Source="{x:Reference image3}"/>
            </DropGestureRecognizer.DropCommandParameter>
        </DropGestureRecognizer>
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>

In my ViewModel, I have written commands to handle the drag-and-drop logic:
[ObservableProperty]
public double firstImageOpacity = 0.5;

[ObservableProperty]
public double secondImageOpacity = 0.5;

public bool isDroppedSuccessfully;

[ObservableProperty]
public bool isAllow = true;

And Methods:
[RelayCommand]
 private void DragCompleted()
 {
     if (!isDroppedSuccessfully)
     {
         IsAllow = true;
     }
     isDroppedSuccessfully = false;
 }

 [RelayCommand]
 public void DragStarting(Image image)
 {
     if (image != null)
     {
         var filename = image.Source.ToString();
         TempImage = filename.Replace("File: ", "");
     }
 }



 [RelayCommand]
 public void DragOver(Image image)
 {
     var secondImage = image.Source.ToString().Replace("File: ", "");

     IsAllow = true;

     if (TempImage == secondImage)
     {
         IsAllow = true;
         return;
     }
     else
     {
         if (IsAllow)
         {
             IsAllow = false;
         }
     }
 }

 [RelayCommand]
 public void Drop(Image image)
 {
     IsAllow = true;

     isDroppedSuccessfully = true;

     image.Opacity = 1;
 }

 [RelayCommand]
 public void DragComplete()
 {
     if (!isDroppedSuccessfully)
     {
         IsAllow = true;
     }
     isDroppedSuccessfully = false;
 }

Basic logic - We drag an image onto two cards, when we hover the image over a card (Image), we check if the image of the card matches the dragged one. if images matches - do some logic (setting the opacity) I made a small test logic for validation that uses [ObservableProperty] isAllow.
So, the problem appears when I drag an image over the wrong image, in which case I can no longer drop it even into the correct image.
In other words, if the user drags the image immediately into the correct card (image) the logic works fine, but if I drag and hover over the wrong card (image), I can no longer drop the image into the correct card. (as in the gif below)
Does anyone have any ideas? Maybe it's not a bug at all, but a problem with my validation logic and I'm not implementing validation correctly?
Gif of the test program running: https://imgur.com/a/80v4lZf

There's a logical error here, IsAllow turns false and through the binding that disables both drop targets.  Instead AllowDrop must always be true, use the DragOver event to disable the drop.

Oh, that makes sense.
But can you tell me please, how to use the DragOver event to disable the drop?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/gestures/drag-and-drop?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=windows#handle-the-dragover-event

You can put the code used to match in the dropcommand instead of the dropovercommand. This is the way to set the IsAllow always be ture before you drop the image down.
[RelayCommand]
 public void Drop(Image image)
 {
     IsAllow = false;     
     var secondImage = image.Source.ToString().Replace("File: ", "");

     if (TempImage == secondImage)
     {
         IsAllow = true;
         isDroppedSuccessfully = true;
         image.Opacity = 1;
         return;
     }
     else
     {
         if (IsAllow)
         {
             IsAllow = false;
         }
     }

     
 }


Well, I tried as you said. But new problem appear - If you drag a picture onto the wrong card (Image), the card is replaced - which is certainly not a desirable result.
Whatever I do I do not know how to prohibit it in the drop command itself. So, one guy here advised me to do validations in dragover.
Any ideas?
Gif - https://imgur.com/a/of6bjPI

Sorry, I made a mistake. The IsAllow should be set to false before you drop.
